# Boostrap carousel not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following carousel does not seem to work.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="number-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#number-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#number-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#number-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item-active">
      <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-1.jpg" style="height: 500px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-2.jpg" style="height: 500px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-3.jpg" style="height: 500px;" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#number-carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#number-carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I am unable to find the issue. What is happening?

Comment: This should not be hyphenated: `<div class="item-active">` It's `<div class="item active">` Refer to the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.carousel{
    background: #2f4357;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel .item img{
    margin: 0 auto; /* Align slide image horizontally center */
}
.bs-example{
 margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>   
        <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://www.iwa2006beijing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/school-fish-thailand-photography-images-ecard_9.jpg" alt="First Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://aquarium.ucsd.edu/images/yellow_tang.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Pterois_volitans_Manado-e_edit.jpg" alt="Third Slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working jsfiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/zafddcx4/6/

```
<div id="number-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#number-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#number-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#number-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-1.jpg" style="height: 500px;">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-2.jpg" style="height: 500px;">

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-3.jpg" style="height: 500px;">

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#number-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#number-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Your version throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by this incorrect class name `<div class="item-active">`. It should be `<div class="item active">`

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/myy0qup7/